# How can I distort the distribution of a set of random numbers?

Tags: javascript, math, random, numbers, distribution

I want to craft an algorithm that will give me numbers that are random in the sense that I have no idea what they'll be, but at the same time, numbers that are closer to `0` have to be more likely to occur as output while those closer to `1` must be less likely.  I'd like to play around with both linear and exponential distributions, so please give at least hints for implementing both.

I've thought and thought about how to approach this issue, but I still don't even have a clue, so any pointers would be appreciated.

NOTE: I'm not looking to discuss, nor do I yet understand, the intricacies of "true" vs. "pseudo" randomness... This has nothing to do with security or cryptography, and for it I'll simply be using Javascript's `Math.random()` as a seed, just so we're all clear about what I'm asking.

Comment: You can use an exponential function but you will have to use density of probabilities, or you can establish a range for example, P(0 <= x <= 0.1)=0.5, P(0.1 < x <= 0.2) = 0.3 and P( 0.2 < x <= 1) = 0.2

Comment: Sorry, but could you give me a quick primer on the notation that you're using?  I made this simple graphing script so that I could understand the stuff better through illustrations, but it isn't really working. Maybe you could have a look at that as well? http://jsfiddle.net/eg3bU/2/

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Got it working... :) Check it out! http://jsfiddle.net/RTbrL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var random = Math.pow(Math.random(), 2);
```

Comment: Can you provide just a little more elaboration of this? It's really hard to wrap my head around what effect this will have, due to the trippiness of random numbers, but it seems interesting.

Comment: It gives you random number between 0 and 1. Number is more likely to be around 0 than around 1. If you increase number 2, random number will be even more likely around 0.

Comment: How might I get a linearly decreasing distribution? `var rand = 2*Math.random()`?

Comment: 2*Math.random() will just give you number between 0 and 1.9999999999999999... any number has equal change to come up.

Comment: Ah, I see.. So then how would one get a linear equialent?

Comment: BTW, I just created this script to graph different types of distribution functions easily. It's all working now. http://jsfiddle.net/RTbrL/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Poisson distribution, probably you can use it for your own purposes, essentially a poisson distribution is not deterministic, but it has a certain frequency of occurrence: wikipedia has a good introductory info about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Algorithm:

```
algorithm poisson random number (Knuth):
init:
     Let L ← e−λ, k ← 0 and p ← 1.
do:
     k ← k + 1.
     Generate uniform random number u in [0,1] and let p ← p × u.
while p > L.
return k − 1.
```