# What's the linear equivalent of this exponential distortion of random distribution?

Tags: javascript, random, distribution, number-theory

I [got this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13451302/1597180) answer earlier today for how to distort a random number seed toward one bound of the range:

```
var random = Math.pow(Math.random(), 2);
```

But that obviously distorts it along an exponential curve.. How can I make it linear?

Also, kind of relevant: I just created this simple script to visualize different types of distributions. It may be helpful for this question: http://jsfiddle.net/RTbrL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing a one-sided [triangular distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Generating_Triangular-distributed_random_variates).

If so, try

```
var random = 1.0 - Math.sqrt(Math.random());
```

or

```
var random = Math.abs(Math.random() - Math.random());
```

Comment: Although, what's the difference between the two snippets you provided?

Comment: @adlwalrus: There may be a performance difference (but I cannot predict which one will be faster.)

Comment: Is that to say they're functionally identical, then?

Comment: @adlwalrus: I believe they are algebraically identical, but you may see a difference with a PRNG.

Answer (score 1):

Like so?

```
var rand = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 5 ) % 5;
```

`rand` goes from 0 to 4.

[% in Javascript is Modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: Nope, not really. That's actually not what I want at all. Pull up your console on my jsfiddle, and notice how the bar graph goes in a curve. I'd like the edges of all the bars to line up in a line.

Comment: I don't want to modify the range.  Only how the output will be distributed over the old range.